# AngularJS Email Validation Fails

Tags: angularjs

You can test from the original address: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D

It fails when you remove the dot. How can I add that to requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The perceived problem lies in the fact that an email without a dot is perfectly legal. bob@localhost is a valid email address. Until the RFC spec changes to require the dot, your choices are to apply extra validation client side via regex or handle this server side. See this post for a much lengthier explanation.

[Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)